# Custom archive.php: retrieve right post categories?

Tags: categories, archives

I'm using a child theme where I edit archive.php. When somebody clicks on a post's category, I want the archive page to display all posts which share ALL of the categories of this post at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php 

    $post_cats = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_id() );

    $myquery= new WP_Query( array(
        'category__and' => $post_cats,
    ) );

    if($myquery->have_posts()) :  ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
            ?>

        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php

            while($myquery->have_posts()) : 
            $myquery->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );

    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
```

Strange enough, my archive page now ALWAYS displays posts which precisely share the categories 23 and 11 - even if the post's categories are different from these!

Additional info, which may have something to do with the problem: Before getting to this code solution, I worked with other solutions where I also used something like `'category__and' => array(23,11)`; this was in order to figure out the main function, before I then installed the `wp_get_post_categories` part. Maybe this could be where `23,11` come from, but I don't know how and why they are fixed now...

Thankful for every hint!

Requin

Comment: Can you clarify: If a post has two categories: Books & Movies, say, and the user clicks *just* on Books, you want to show all posts that have both the Books *and* Movies category? Or would you just be trying to show posts with the Books category?

Comment: If a post has x categories and the user clicks just on one of them, I want to show all posts that have all x categories at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

the wp_get_post_categories function will return the categories for the first post in the loop not the post the user has just clicked on.

You need to pass the categories from the previous post to use in your custom loop.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions how to do this? :)

Comment: Got it: The id of the category the archive is about is in queried_object->term_id.